# Removing the imaginary part of input impedance of a Monopole in HFSS

Tags: antenna, impedance-matching, input-impedance

I am building a Monopole in HFSS for my project. Its structure is shown here :

[image]

The input impedance at the desired frequency is :

[image]

Now i need to eliminate the imaginary part , so that the voltage and current be in phase with each other. Therefore , i need to add a capacitor as a lumped element with this imaj. value by creating a sheet and assigning it as a lumped RLC. However , i don't know where to put this sheet as this is my first time to design a matching circuit using HFSS. I have tried to insert it at the bottom of the monopole :
[image]

But i don't get any effect in the input impedance. Here is my model parameters :

[image]

Finally , i need to find a way to eliminate this imaj. part. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know HFSS, but nevertheless I see a problem with your approach. Your working frequency seems to be 6 MHz, which is really low. This means you would need a huge RF capacitor (like  >100pF) to compensate. This capacitance is hardly achievable with a lumped element. You would need a discrete capacitor instead.

Comment: please specify  why we will need a huge RF capacitor in more details